# Migrating Spring boot JPA(MySQL) to JPA(PostgreSQL) throws an ERROR

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a spring boot web application with JPA and MySQL is the database. I have to migrate from MySQL DB to PostgreSQL.
Some of the table(entity) cause to ERROR while configuring PostgreSQL to application.

'create' option of the JPA is working properly.
 but when changing create to 'update' program is terminating with error.

The error is

'column i.indproc does not exist
  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "i.indpred".
  Position: 610'

```
ERROR 31134 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
```

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'..... 
[PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory`

```
n.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing index information: table_user
```

`Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column i.indproc does not exist`

Comment: Well, the column `i.indproc` doesn't exist. What more can we help with that?

Comment: drop the database and work with directly update.

Comment: I haven't  `i.indproc` named column anywhere in my source

Answer (score 0):

I hit similar errors.
Upgrading the postgreql maven dependency to the latest version fixed my errors.
In Aug 2019,  it's

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```